# Blazor - Proper way to apply JS after DOM is loaded and rendered

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have had a hell of a time trying to get JS to play friendly with the Blazor lifecycle. I have a Blazor Server web app, using .NET 5. My website is heavy on images, and I use certain JS libraries to arrange images in a pretty way on the screen (masonry; lightboxes, etc.)

I have been really struggling with applying DOM-dependent JS. A lot of the JS code is meant to take DOM layout variability into account - for example, when an image loads, I have a JS script that is meant to get the width of the image as it is rendered on the screen (this varies, as it leans on css `object-fit:scale-down`) and then it resizes other DOM elements based on this calculation.

The problem is, I usually have to implement a loop (see `SetWidth()` in my code below) to apply and re-apply the JS script an arbitrary number of times so it can finally execute once the DOM finally finishes shifting around. This is ugly for obvious reasons, and it doesn't always work. I have pasted a sample of the approach I am taking below, just to illustrate my general approach. Can someone please tell me how to do this properly?

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject ResizeListener listener

<div class="text-overflow-dots" style="width:@($"{_widthLeader}px;")">
    @ChildContent
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string IdLeader { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    DotNetObjectReference<OverflowContainerDots> ObjectReference;

    private int _widthLeader { get; set; } = 0;

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// page lifecycle
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
        if (firstRender)
        {
            ObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);

            // Subscribe to the OnResized event. This will do work when the browser is resized.
            listener.OnResized += WindowResized;

            await SetWidth();

            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// DOM
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private async Task SetWidth()
    {
        do
        {
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("OverflowContainer.getWidthOfLeader", IdLeader, ObjectReference);
            await Task.Delay(50);
        } while (_widthLeader == 0);
    }

    // This method will be called when the window resizes.
    // It is ONLY called when the user stops dragging the window's edge. (It is already throttled to protect your app from perf. nightmares)
    private async void WindowResized(object _, BrowserWindowSize window)
    {
        await SetWidth();

        StateHasChanged();
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /// JS-invokable methods
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [JSInvokable("UpdateWidth")]
    public void UpdateDivWidth(int width)
    {
        if (_widthLeader != width)
        {
            _widthLeader = width;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

And my JS:

```
var OverflowContainer = OverflowContainer || {};
OverflowContainer.getWidthOfLeader = function (elementIdLeader, dotNetObject) {

    var leader = document.getElementById(elementIdLeader);
    if (leader === null)
        return;

    style = window.getComputedStyle(leader);

    dotNetObject.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateWidth', parseInt(style.getPropertyValue('width')));
};
```

Comment: I'm curious what you're up to.  I see JS calling a Blazor method, which in turn calls JS.  What is the purpose of using Blazor at all, rather than just pure JS?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 In the example I pasted above, the razor component triggers the JS (in which the div width is calculated), and then the JS passes the calculated value to the razor component via a `JSInvokable` function, which then updates a variable and renders the change to the DOM. The reason I chose to do it this way was because I thought the blazor paradigm was 'do as much as possible with blazor, and use JS for whatever can't be done." I am curious if I am just missing the mark in terms of what is considered "best practice" in terms of working with the `JSRuntime`

Comment: In my view, Javascript shouldn't be involved in maintaining layout-- for that, I'd use only CSS (Blazor has Bootstrap installed ready-to-use by default).  I used to use a lot of little hacks like that-- getting dimension of a parent div on resize so that I could scale children and so on-- but I really don't find that necessary any more-- a couple days learning Bootstrap really made things easier for me.  I use JS for things that REALLY are untouchable by Blazor right now-- things like recording audio, getting the start and end position of selected text and so on.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 I see what you're saying, and I appreciate the sentiment. The example I pasted above was meant to just illustrate the approach I'm currently taking to apply JS to manipulate the DOM. I have a few JS libraries that I *need* to use, however, and I am just trying to figure out what the "blazor best practice" paradigm is to apply the JS only once the DOM is finished rendering.

Comment: Yeah, if you have a compelling reason to use JS, then go ahead and use Interop.  Maybe to keep things clean you could make a special collection of components.  For example, you could have **RelativeResizer.razor** that did some JS stuff, maybe using a string `[Parameter]` for what class name it should work on, and put it on whatever page needed that functionality.  That might actually be a library that people would like you to share.